# Animate UICollectionView items on constraint change in custom layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I'm using a custom UICollectionview Layout that displays the items in a circle. On a swipe up I reset the constraints on my collectionview and animate those constraint changes. I would like my items to animate with the constraint change so it's one smooth experience.

I get them to animate but only after the constraint change (I think), it looks messy and strange, check the screencast out here: http://cl.ly/ZmA0

This is the code in the swipe gesture method:

```
- (void)foo:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.collectionView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
        make.height.equalTo(self.collectionView.mas_width);
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).offset(50);
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        CircleLayout *layout = (CircleLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what MASConstraintMaker is (and the video is not working). 
But within the performBatchUpdates block you are getting the collection view layout. What are you doing with it? it unused. Maybe that can point you to the right solution.